# create a condition that separates text.tag when parsing xml with python

Tags: python, xml

I have this xml file that i dawnload from a source filename file.xml that inside of it`s Details have two OrderDetail, what i do with this is that i decode it and i write a new xml file in witch i parse it to get some information from.

```
    <root>
        <Details>
            <OrderDetail  ParentLineID="">H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy963LbyJbn+/
            lMxLwDwtO7qnaMYeF+8d7VHZJolV0lWypRLu/u6g4HCC
            QljClCmwTLdn+aFzkvd57k4EJSJAGIyJWQ8E+Ve3qqLd7
            XSlxW/jLzl3//ty83E+UPNpvHyfTHZ/oL7dm//ev//B9/P
            06m4/hqMQvS7==
            </OrderDetail>
            <OrderDetail  ParentLineID="">H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy963LbyJbn+/
                lMxLwDwtO7qnaMYeF+8d7VHZJolV0lWypRLu/u6g4HCC
                QljClCmwTLdn+aFzkvd57k4EJSJAGIyJWQ8E+Ve3qqLd7
                XSlxW/jLzl3//ty83E+UPNpvHyfTHZ/oL7dm//ev//B9/P
                06m4/hqMQvS7==
                </OrderDetail>
        </Details>
     </root>



tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
DEST_FILE_NAME = "XMLparser\\decompresed.xml"

 def translate_to_file():
for child in root.iter('OrderDetail'):
        child.get('ParentLineID')
        result = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(child.text), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode('utf-8') 
        with open(DEST_FILE_NAME, "w") as file:
          file.write(result)  
 def read_file():
     with open(DEST_FILE_NAME) as file:
        return file.readlines()


 def clean_file(lines):
      with open(DEST_FILE_NAME, 'w') as file:
         lines = filter(lambda x: x.strip(), lines)
         file.writelines(lines)

 def main():
      translate_to_file()

      lines = read_file()
      clean_file(lines)

 main()
```

when this file is decodedcrates an xml file
how can i create two separated xml files for reach OrderDetail ? so i take the first base64  decompresed and create an XML file . i take the other base64 decompresed and create a separate XML file ?

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve]. What's the python code?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the expected output in each case?